# What version of GLSL is used in the iPhone(s)?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glsl

I know that iPhone uses OpenGL ES 2.0, but I don't know the version of the underlying language GLSL. Is it 1.3, 1.4, 2.0, or other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found it myself, thanks to the _____VERSION_____ predefined macro. The GLSL ES specification used is the 1.0, which is based on the GLSL version 1.20. The OpengGL ES 2.0 and GLSL ES 1.0 specifications are available for download at http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/.

Comment: To be clear while the GLSL ES 1.0 spec might be based on the GLSL 1.20 spec there are plenty of things in GLSL 1.20 that are **NOT** in GLSL ES 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("GLSL Version = %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
printf("GL Version = %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

On IOS 5.1, this prints out:

```
GL Version = OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE

GLSL Version = OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0
```