# glsl es const mat2 array

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles, rendermonkey

I try to compile the following code in Open GL ES 2.0 (in RenderMonkey):

```
const mat2 ma[2] =  mat2[2](
                     mat2( vec2(0.0, -1.0), vec2(1.0, 0.0) ),
                     mat2( vec2(0.0, -1.0), vec2(1.0, 0.0) )
                    );
```

But compiler says:

```
OpenGL ES Preview Window: Compiling vertex shader API(OpenGL ES) /Effect Group 1/Effect1/Pass 0/Vertex Program/ ... failure
   COMPILE ERROR: API(OpenGL ES) /Effect Group 1/Effect1/Pass 0/Vertex Program/ (13): ERROR: 0:13: 'constructor' : if a matrix argument is given to a matrix constructor, it is an error to have any other arguments. 
   COMPILE ERROR: API(OpenGL ES) /Effect Group 1/Effect1/Pass 0/Vertex Program/ (10): ERROR: 0:10: '=' :  cannot assign to 'const array of 2X2 matrix of float'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*EDIT*]

In webgl/chrome, I get this:

```
ERROR: 0:4: 'ma' : arrays may not be declared constant since they cannot be initialized 
ERROR: 0:4: '=' : syntax error
```

It doesn't look good.

Possibly related: [How to define constant array in GLSL (OpenGL ES 2.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467110/how-to-define-constant-array-in-glsl-opengl-es-2-0)

---

*Desktop GL...*

Your code works for me, however I get this without setting a version:

```
warning C7551: OpenGL first class arrays require #version 120
```

Can you provide a [`#version`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Version) string in RenderMonkey?

I doubt this is the case but a *really* old card or drivers may be a factor.

I don't think you need the second `2` either: `const mat2 ma[2] =  mat2[](...` is fine

Comment: You should try to run it on GL ES device, like android, or webGL. And on the RenderMonkey make sure you use GL ES effect group. If so - you can use only #version 100. #version 120 - for desktop GL

Comment: @tower120 My bad, I completely missed the GL ES part. I'm not sure it's possible, but don't know for sure. Just tried in webgl.