# Array declaration in metal shader

Tags: ios, shader, metal

It is possible to use array in GLSL like this:

```
float[4](.5, .5, .5, .5)
```

Is it possible to use arrays in metal shader, if yes how can I declare it?
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you use `float4` instead?

Comment: no, I need more then 7 items, it was just example

Comment: This would probably work: `float mytype[7] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };`.

Comment: doesn't work, "ERROR: expected expression"

Comment: Did you accidentally copy-paste the period `.` after the declaration? @trojanfoe's code works for me (though you can also omit the `=` to use C++'s uniform initialization syntax; the result is the same).

Comment: Well, Im doing something wrong, but it doesn't work for me https://www.screencast.com/t/E60gjQKVLBf

Comment: Hm, when I use without = (float a[7]{ 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1. };) it doesn't produce error, but when Im trying to take value like a[0] it is always 0. for any indexes. When I do a[0] = 1., then yes it is 1., but after initialization it looks empty

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10470628/155187) may have a workaround for you.

Answer (score 0):

It works almost like in c++:

```
float array[3] = float[3](0.5,0.5,0.5);
float array[3] = float[3](0.5);// also works, but you can't initialize the entire array with that number, it's going to be (0.5,0.0,0.0)
```

see: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Arrays