# Transpose a mat4 in OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I'd like to transpose a matrix in my OpenGL ES 2.0 vertex shader, but apparently my iPad 3 doesn't support GLSL `#version 120`, which is needed for the built-in function `transpose(mat4)`.

I know there are options to work around that, like transposing the matrix on the CPU before passing it to the graphics chip, but it would make my shader a lot simpler if I could transpose it there.

**So, is there an option to `transpose` a mat4 in a shader on an iOS 6 device?**

Another thing: The question

[What version of GLSL is used in the iPhone(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456669/what-version-of-glsl-is-used-in-the-iphones)

says that OpenGL ES 2.0 uses GLSL 1.20. So why doesn't `#version 120` work on the iPad 3?

Comment: Did you try it without the #version and with transpose? I am pretty sure it works its on the standard ES 2.0 reference card.

Comment: "*says that OpenGL ES 2.0 uses GLSL 1.20*" No it doesn't. It says that it's "based on" 1.20, not that it *uses* 1.20.

Comment: @JustinMeiners yes I tried that, doesn't work. `transpose` is undefined without `#version 120`.

Comment: @NicolBolas you're right. Do you know which GLSL versions are supported on which iOS device?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried just transposing it yourself?  Is it a performance problem? If not, I would try it because it's something the optimizer should handle and it will take two minutes. Something like:

```
highp mat4 transpose(in highp mat4 inMatrix) {
    highp vec4 i0 = inMatrix[0];
    highp vec4 i1 = inMatrix[1];
    highp vec4 i2 = inMatrix[2];
    highp vec4 i3 = inMatrix[3];

    highp mat4 outMatrix = mat4(
                 vec4(i0.x, i1.x, i2.x, i3.x),
                 vec4(i0.y, i1.y, i2.y, i3.y),
                 vec4(i0.z, i1.z, i2.z, i3.z),
                 vec4(i0.w, i1.w, i2.w, i3.w)
                 );

    return outMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Gonna do that if there's no built-in option.

Comment: There is clearly a problem with the code. `i3.y, i3.y` should be `i2.y, i3.y`. The same is true for z and w.

Answer (score 4):

As the answer to [What version of GLSL is used in the iPhone(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456669/what-version-of-glsl-is-used-in-the-iphones) correctly states, iOS supports OpenGL ES 2.0 with its companion shading language: ESSL 1.0. ESSL 1.0 is based on, but not identical to GLSL 1.20.

There is no built-in transpose function in ESSL 1.0, so you'll need to implement your own.