# GLSL's transpose alternative in GLSL ES?

Tags: glsl, glsles

I was trying to convert GLSL to GLSL ES and got this problem: transpose function isn't available in GLSL ES.

```
mat3 yuv = transpose(yuv_matrix);
```

So how I can use it? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Duplicate of [Transpose a mat4 in OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034677/transpose-a-mat4-in-opengl-es-2-0-glsl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 3x3 matrix can be [transposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) as follows:

```c
mat3 yuv = mat3(
    vec3(yuv_matrix[0].x, yuv_matrix[1].x, yuv_matrix[2].x),
    vec3(yuv_matrix[0].y, yuv_matrix[1].y, yuv_matrix[2].y),
    vec3(yuv_matrix[0].z, yuv_matrix[1].z, yuv_matrix[2].z));
```

Note, the transposed matrix is a matrix which is flipped over its diagonal.

```
(a  b  c) T    (a  d  g)
(d  e  f)    = (b  e  h)
(g  h  i)      (c  f  i)
```

Matrices consist of column vectors. So a matrix can be initialized by vectors, e.g.:

```c
vec3 a, b, c;
mat3 m = mat3(a, b, c);
```

And the vectors of the matrix can be accessed by the index operator, e.g.:

```c
mat3 m;
vec3 v = m[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll try the first code tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, I see bvec2, bvec3, etc. classes and I don't know should I change them to basis vec, vec2, vec3 classes? GLSL ES doesn't have such.

Comment: @EadwineYoun GLSL ES has  `bvec2`, `bvec3` and `bvec4` since version 1.0, see [The OpenGL®  ES Shading Language Version: 1.00 -  4.1 Basic Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) page 18.

Comment: bvec is boolean vector, not basis

Comment: It seems that I don't have it, somewhy. bvec just don't shows as build-in variable.

Comment: @EadwineYoun `bvec` is a type rather than a variable. Anyway you can use an integral data type instead, `ivec2`, `ivec3` ...

Comment: Thanks, GLSL ES doesn't support mat4x3 like matrixes. What should I do with them?

Comment: @EadwineYoun How should I know? For what reason do you need them? Probably you've to use 4x4 matrices.

Comment: @Andrea I didn't mean the type of vector, basis like usual/normal.

Comment: @EadwineYoun then why are bvec2, bvec3 etc relevant to you here?

Comment: @Andrea GameMaker's GLSL ES doesn't support these vectors.

Comment: @EadwineYoun Please consider that this has nothing to do with this question. If you have a further issue, then pleas ask a new question. The reason is, that noone will read this comments here, but a new question will be read by many user, which may help you.